# Unable to install openssh-server via Yum

Tags: linux, ssh, centos7

**OS:** Centos 7.4

**End goal:** Install openssh-server

**current issue:** removing previous copy of sshd

**Preceding scenario:** openssh-server would not update due to yum errors. I attempted to remove openssh-server and then install it via yum in hopes that starting from scratch would clear up any issues. However the current problem is the same as the original.

**Issue:** When trying to install openssh-server, I get an error when Yum tries to rename the existing sshd file:

```
Installing : openssh-server-7.4p1-13.el7_4.x86_64                                                                                            1/1 
Error unpacking rpm package openssh-server-7.4p1-13.el7_4.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/sbin/sshd: cpio: rename
```

I assume the installer is trying to rename the old file before it can install its version. So I tried to rename it myself as root:

```
mv /usr/sbin/sshd /usr/sbin/sshd.old
mv: cannot move ‘/usr/sbin/sshd’ to ‘/usr/sbin/sshd.old’: Operation not permitted
```

My first though is that maybe items in the /usr/sbin directory are immutable. However I am able to rename other files in there (I renamed them back!) And I was able to rename sshd on other centos 7 servers.

In doing research I found recommendations to run the command `lsattr`. However no matter what file/directory I run this command on, there is no output. I have tried running it on other Centos 7 servers and it works there.

The same seems to be for `chattr`, though I am not sure it is should display anny output. Without the use of `lsattr`, I cannot confirm if `chattr` did anything. I ran the following command with the though that perhaps /usr/sbin/sshd is immutable:

```
chattr -i /usr/sbin/sshd
```

The file still cannot be renamed. I am executing all commands as root, the file is owned by root and has r/w/x permissions for root.

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     500K Dec 30 21:08 sshd
```

Also, there are no processes running as sshd according to lsof or ps.

I am not really sure what to make of this, and perhaps my question should be about `lsattr` not outputting anything instead of this question. I suspect I will need to provide additional info, but not sure what. So I will try to update the question with more info upon request. Anyone have any recommendations on things I can try to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: The most common reason for `lsattr` to not give you any output is that the server has been compromised. Blow it away.

Comment: that of course is always a possibility, however the server is pretty new. And the only publicly accessible port is ssh which only allows connections from a specific IP. Its on a rackspace account which gets set up through rackspace so I am wondering if this could be some kind of policy in their default installation perhaps? I don't suppose selinux in permissive mode could do anything could it?

Comment: If the server is recently installed, I'd consider running `rpm -Va` and investigating any discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here was my solution for this problem:

I made new copies of lsattr and chattr.
I used those copies to fix the attributes on the system copies of those programs.
I deleted the system copies and replaced them with my new copies.
I then used chattr to fix the attributes for /usr/sbin/sshd
I removed /usr/sbin/sshd
I installed openssh-server via Yum.

The 3 problem files had the a and u attr flags set on them. I needed to upload new copies because the files for changing the attributes were themselves broken.

Comment: That pretty much proves the server was compromised.